# How to add a forked package to composer.json file

Tags: php, yii, composer-php

I have extended dektrium package and uploaded this package into my GitHub https://github.com/Leopandro/dektrium. I want to add this package into `composer.json`.

I've tried to change this line `"dektrium/yii2-user": "0.9.*@dev"` into `"Leopandro/dektrium/yii2-user"` but nothing has changed.

My `composer.json`:

```
    {
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable" : true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "dektrium/yii2-user": "0.9.*@dev",
        "execut/yii2-widget-bootstraptreeview": "dev-master",
        "2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget": "~1.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
        "paulzi/yii2-adjacency-list": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it:

```js
"repositories":
    [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/Leopandro/yii2-user"
        }
    ],
"require": 
  {
      "dektrium/yii2-user": "master",//master is name of my forked branch
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fork a package that you intend to use, give it a new name! It is now your project that you have to maintain (otherwise, you wouldn't fork it).

Having a new name allows you to add it to Packagist without conflicts, or just use it under it's new name in your projects.

Adding your own repository to a project would be like this inside your `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "your-new/package-name": "~1.0"
}, 
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/Leopandro/dektrium"
    }
]
```

If Composer reacts confused, it may be resolved by deleting the vendor folder, then try again.

On the other hand: Forking a project really is not the right way if the only thing you want to do is change one or two lines that don't exactly fit your use case. I cannot evaluate the impact of your changes, but you should always try to find a solution that does not include forking someone else' code.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can create a brunch in your repo `some-fixes-and-enhancements` and use this brunch name as package version with `dev-` prefix:

```
"require": {
    "dektrium/yii2-user": "dev-some-fixes-and-enhancements", // your branch name here
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/Leopandro/yii2-user"
    }
]
```

Answer (score -2):

In your `composer.json` add a repository section for your fork of `dektrium/yii2-user` like below:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "dektrium/yii2-user",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/Leopandro/dektrium/tree/master/yii2-user",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "classmap": [""]
            }
        }
    }
],
```

You need to change the require section for this package to `dev-master` or what ever version you set in the repositories section above.

```
"require": {
    "dektrium/yii2-user": "dev-master"
},
```

run `composer updade -vvv` to see it updating from your GitHub fork

Comment: Why the "package" type? `"type":"vcs"` with the repository URL is much less typing and hassle, and it will use the autoloading from the repositories `composer.json` - you don't have to add changes in two places (the repo itself and this package here).

Comment: because he used the same name for his fork and the original package. This is not changed in two places, it all goes into the `composer.json` of the project nothing has to be changed in the forked package.